# Array of objects to array

Tags: javascript, beginner, array, json

What would be the "correct" way of transforming an array of objects into an object that contains an array?

Suppose I have this array that contains objects:

```
const paintings = [
  { painting: "Mona Lisa" },
  { painting: "The Starry Night" },
  { painting: "The Last Supper" },
  { painting: "Girl with a Pearl Earring" },
  { painting: "American Gothic" },
  { painting: "The Night Watch" }
];
```

And I would like to transform it into this:

```
const paintings = {
  artworks: [
    "Mona Lisa",
    "The Starry Night",
    "The Last Supper",
    "Girl with a Pearl Earring",
    "American Gothic",
    "The Night Watch"
  ]
};
```

I know that I can accomplish this with two nested loops like below, but is there a more "elegant" way of doing it? I think that these tasks are nowadays usually solved using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) functions but I find them a bit confusing to use. I would like to learn though!

```
const paintingsNew = {
  artworks: []
};

for (const painting of paintings) {
  for (const val of Object.values(painting).values()) {
    paintingsNew.artworks.push(val);
  }
}

console.log(paintingsNew);

// { artworks:
//    [ 'Mona Lisa',
//      'The Starry Night',
//      'The Last Supper',
//      'Girl with a Pearl Earring',
//      'American Gothic',
//      'The Night Watch' ] }
```

Comment: `artworks` maps every  `{painting:"MonaLisa", artist: ...}` to its `painting`. In Computer Science a _projection_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code flattens the entire array of {} objects, indiscriminately flattening all properties. It does not mind, if there is only one single property, but it does not make *sense* semantically, especially if the array is named `paintings`.

Rather consider the resulting array a projection/mapping to a single property `painting`.

For a consistent array check and take only the `painting` property.

```
for (const p of paintings) {
  if ("painting" in p) {
    paintingsNew.artworks.push(p.painting);
  }
}
```

The extra `if` protects against `undefined` entering corrupted data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Array.prototype.map` you can write something like this:

```
const paintings = [
  { painting: "Mona Lisa" },
  { painting: "The Starry Night" },
  { painting: "The Last Supper" },
  { painting: "Girl with a Pearl Earring" },
  { painting: "American Gothic" },
  { painting: "The Night Watch" }
];

const paintingsNew = {
  artworks: []
};

paintings.map(x => {
  paintingsNew.artworks.push(x);
});
```

When you use `map` it practically iterates over every item of the array. We have to pass a callback function accepting the `currentValue` (here the `x` argument), and optionally the `index` and the `array`.

You can (and normally should) return some calculated value in the callback function. Since here everything you want is to create a new object containing the array, you push each item to the array inside the object `paintingsNew`. You don't even need `map` for this, you can just write:

```
const paintingsNew = {
  artworks: paintings // paintings is defined before
};
```

However I suppose you'd have some further requirements, which you could work out inside the callback function of the `map`. As suggested by @Joop Eggen, you could check if the key `painting` is present in the object:

```
paintings.map(x => {
  if ('painting' in x) {
    paintingsNew.artworks.push(x);
  }
});
```

Now this would make more sense when using `map`. You could certainly apply some more advanced logic if your initial array is more diverse  and you'd like to create an output object with more complex structure.

EDIT: Immediatelly after posting I saw you want to get only the value for the key `painting`. This means in the `map` callback you push `x.painting` instead of just `x`.

```
paintings.map(x => {
  if ('painting' in x) {
    paintingsNew.artworks.push(x.painting);
  }
});
```

Comment: You are misusing `map`.  It is for creating a new array like this: `const newPaintings = paintings.map(x => x.painting)`, not to execute side-effects. You should be using `.forEach()`.

Comment: @RoToRa thank you for the comment. You're right, `.forEach()` is more appropriate for this. I used `.map()` because the OP stated in the question he/she wanted to use `map` or `reduce`.

Comment: if you [edit] your answer to not suggest calling `.push()` inside the callback to `.map()` then I would consider changing my vote...